# Re-install MySql in mac os x 10.6.6

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-snow-leopard, reinstall

I had earlier installed mysql-5.1.50-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg and then uninstalled it using the below belo command (found in stackoverflow)

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
Password:
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
$ rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
$ sudo vi /etc/hostconfig
$ sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql*
$ cd /Library/Receipts/
```

Then I have tried to reinstall from mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg.

However I am getting the below error:

The installation failed
The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: Next time, be a bit more careful with your wildcards, in case you have a preference pane called "My Shoes" (or whatnot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the installer log — open the Installer; press command-L to show the log, and command-3 to increase the detail level; attempt the install.

**The below is a summary of the comments**

***OP**: The error log displays the below mentioned*

> Feb 21 21:30:28 Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro installd[387]: ./postflight: chown: mysql: Invalid argument

**Paul**: Looks like you don't have a user "mysql". Confirm that by running dscl . list /Users|grep mysql. You should see _mysql as the result.

***OP**:  running `dscl . list /Users|grep mysql`  It did not return anything*

**Paul**: Your mysql user is missing. [Here are instructions for creating a MySQL user][1] Do that, and then run the installer

***OP**: Thanks a lot it worked. I have created the mysql user and the group as suggested by you. The ran the installer. It was installed.*

Comment: Hi the error log displays the below mentioned:  Feb 21 21:30:28 Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro Installer[378]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x11940f8d0 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg”."

Comment: Prior the above message  Feb 21 21:30:28 Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro installd[387]: ./postflight: chown: mysql: Invalid argument

Comment: Looks like you don't have a user "mysql". Confirm that by running `dscl . list /Users|grep mysql`. You should see `_mysql` as the result.

Comment: Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:~ sarbbottam$ dscl . list /Users|grep mysql  
Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:~ sarbbottam$ 
 It did not return anything

Comment: Yup. Your mysql user is missing. Weird! Here are instructions for creating a MySQL user: http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/mysql-on-os-x.html#Anchor-User Do that, and then run the installer.

Comment: can I also do it by installing apple developer tool from the cd that came along with MacBook Pro?

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul Schreiber, it worked. I have created the mysql user and the group as suggested by you. The ran the installer. It was installed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am able to install mysql and start it via system preferences, but not sure how to run login. It has been installed @ Sarbbottam-Bandyopadhyays-MacBook-Pro:bin sarbbottam$ pwd
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/bin, i tried executing sudo mysql @ the abole directory, however I got the "sudo: mysql: command not found" error. Please guide.

Comment: Could you put the actually solution in your answer, instead of hiding them in the comments?