# MySQL - The Installation Failed on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I had an old instalation of MySQL but it wasn't working very well.. so i googled how to completley remove it and found this:

http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html

and then did:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

And now i'm getting this on a new install:[image: The Instalation Failed]

i also ran this commands:

```
    sudo rm /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/_mysql.plist
sudo rm /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/_mysql.plist
sudo rm /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql.bom
sudo rm /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql..plist
```

any help on this?

Many Thanks,
Mr. Nizzle.

UPDATE

Installer Error Log Says:

```
Apr 13 00:18:31 nizzlesmymac installd[3203]: PackageKit: Install Failed: PKG: post-flight scripts for "com.mysql.mysql"\nError Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x101e45ac0 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package ‚Äúmysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg‚Äù." {\n    NSFilePath = "./postflight";\n    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cmysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg\U201d.";\n    NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg";\n    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.mysql.mysql";\n}
```

UPDATE

this is the full Installation Error Log:

```
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-430.1
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Hardware: MacBookPro8,1 @ 2.30 GHz (x 4), 4096 MB RAM
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J3250)
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/Pu/Pu2sD3XgEiuSw9qDGflH8++++TI/-Tmp-/
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: HOME=/Users/rguillen
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: USER=rguillen
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: LOGNAME=rguillen
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-4vyaek/org.x:0
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-K54BQh/Listeners
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-mwoG2K/Render
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: MySQL 5.5.11-community for Mac OS X  Installation Log
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Opened from: /Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg
Apr 13 08:26:50 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac runner[188]: Administrator authorization granted.
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: ================================================================================
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: User picked Standard Install
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Choices selected for installation:
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]:   Install: "MySQL 5.5.11-community for Mac OS X"
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]:     mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg : com.mysql.mysql : 5.5.11.1.0
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: ================================================================================
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: -[IFPKGDerivedDocument sortedPackageLocations]: result = (\n    "file://localhost"\n)
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: location = file://localhost
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Will use PK session
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Starting installation:
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 263.32 GB (263317995520 bytes).
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/Pu/Pu2sD3XgEiuSw9qDGflH8++++TI/-Tmp-//Install.181cTqWGQ"
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: IFPKInstallElement (1 packages)
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <1 packages, destination=/>
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: packages=(\n    "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg>"\n)
Apr 13 08:27:07 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zzzivhrRnAmviuee+++++++++++/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root/usr/local, uid=0)
Apr 13 08:27:22 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: Executing script "./preflight" in /Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources
Apr 13 08:27:22 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zzzivhrRnAmviuee+++++++++++/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root (1 items) to /
Apr 13 08:27:24 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg/Contents/Resources
Apr 13 08:27:24 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: ./postflight: chown: mysql: Invalid argument
Apr 13 08:27:25 NizzlesMyMac installd[191]: PackageKit: Install Failed: PKG: post-flight scripts for "com.mysql.mysql"\nError Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x100407570 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package ‚Äúmysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg‚Äù." {\n    NSFilePath = "./postflight";\n    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cmysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg\U201d.";\n    NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg";\n    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.mysql.mysql";\n}
Apr 13 08:27:25 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 UserInfo=0x117116b40 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package ‚Äúmysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg‚Äù."
Apr 13 08:27:25 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Apr 13 08:27:26 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: IFDInstallController 6F03890 state = 7
Apr 13 08:27:26 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Apr 13 08:27:26 NizzlesMyMac Installer[181]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

For pretty colors see here instead: http://pastie.org/1791314

Comment: When you get that message in the installer, open the installer log (`Installer` -> `Window` -> `Installer Log`) and see what errors are being reported.

Comment: @Ned Deily Just added the error log line on the body of the question

Comment: @mu is too short Yes, My bad, i forgot about stackexchange, Thank You

Comment: That's not very helpful, is it?  You could try expanding the Installer Log by selecting `Show All Logs` on the `Detail Level` control at the top of the `Installer Log` window.  That *might* give more information about exactly where the failure occurred.  If all else fails, try rebooting if you haven't already.

Comment: @Ned Deily Full Log http://pastie.org/1791314

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-install MySql in mac os x 10.6.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787/re-install-mysql-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log you posted, the failure is here:

```
/postflight: chown: mysql: Invalid argument
```

There are lots of reports of this error; its usual cause is the lack of a `mysql` user name.  There is a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787/re-install-mysql-in-mac-os-x-10-6-6) with a solution to follow [here](http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/mysql-on-os-x.html#Anchor-User).

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle I also receiving the same error while Installing MYSQL on MOUNTAIN LION. I have posted almost the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319267/mysql-server-version-5-0-96-installation-fails-on-mac-mountain-lion/13319329#13319329. I am not sure whether I should create a another _mysql group another, whereas it is already present.